# Remove duplicate objects from javascript array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects

```
var arr = [
 {id: 1, name: 'Apple'}, {id: 1, name: 'Mango'}, {id: 2, name: 'Pear'}, {id: 2, name: 'Orange'}
];
```

How to make sure `arr` contains only unique objects?

Comment: What do you consider unique? No duplicate IDs? In the eyes of JavaScript each of those objects *is* unique. Even if you had `[{id: 1, name: 'Apple'}, {id: 1, name: 'Apple'}]` the two objects might still be unique if their references point to different places.

Answer (score 0):

Using **[Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)**. When into filter function returns true, the element is maintained. The temporary variable `idsMemo` is created to store and check if the **id** already exists.

```js
var arr = [{id: 1, name: 'Apple'}, {id: 1, name: 'Mango'}, {id: 2, name: 'Pear'}, {id: 2, name: 'Orange'}]
var idsMemo = [];
arr = arr.filter(function(obj){
  return idsMemo.indexOf(obj.id) == -1 ? !!idsMemo.push(obj.id) : false
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(arr))
```